# How to avoid error text display when switched to a tab

Tags: wpf, xaml

Based on the answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60615672/how-to-flash-error-text-using-wpf-animation) question I am able to flash my error text.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="False" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </TextBlock.Triggers>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In my application there are number of tabs. The `TextBlock` is in one tab, the problem now I am facing is whenever I switch to this tab the `ErrorText` is flashing if it was previously shown. I think this is because I specify the `RoutedEvent="Loaded"`. I want the error to be shown only if it is explicitly set again. Is there any way to achieve this using 'xaml` itself?

View model logic to specify the error string given below.

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == nameof(this.CurrentValue))
        {
            if (this.ShowErrorMessage)
            {
                return ValidationErrorMessage;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you switch to the newer [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.8) interface, you should be able to handle the `ErrorsChanged` event.

Comment: I have to make this working in .NET 4.0. Is there any way to clear the errortext from `xaml` when the animation is finished ?

Comment: How would that solve your original issue?

Comment: My validation works like this. When user enters an invalid value I set the property `ValidationErrorMessage` with proper error message and set the UI control back to the valid previous value. The errortext is flashed for few seconds and hidden. So if I can clear the `ValidationErrorMessage` after the animation, no error will be shown when the control is reloaded.